# How to resume animation after clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant get my head around this, been trying many many different ways but no luck.. Basically, I'm trying to pause the animation on mouseOver and resume it on mouseOut. I was able to make it pause by simply using clearTimeout() but I have no idea on how to resume it back on. Please kindly advise me with a correct solution and syntax.

Thank you in advance!

```
(function ($) {    
    $.fn.simpleSpy = function (interval, limit) {      
        limit = limit || 3;
        interval = interval || 3000;
        items = [];     

        return this.each(function () {
            $list = $(this),
            currentItem = 0,
            total = 0; // initialise later on

            var i = 0;
            smplet = $list.clone();
            smplet.css("display","none");

            $("body").append(smplet);
            total = smplet.find('> li').length;

            $list.find('> li').filter(':gt(' + (0) + ')').remove();
            $list.css("display","");
            height = $list.find('> li:first').height(); 
            $list.wrap('<div class="spyWrapper" />').parent().css({ height : 55, position:"relative", overflow:"hidden" });  

            $('.close').click(function(){           
                clearTimeout(timec);

                if(currentItem == 0 && smplet.length != 1)
                    delitem=total;
                else
                    delitem=currentItem - 1;

                smplet.find('> li').eq(delitem).remove();

                currentItem--;

                var temp=smplet.find('> li').eq(currentItem).clone();               
                var $insert = temp.css({
                    "margin-top":-height-height/3,
                    opacity : 0
                }).prependTo($list);

                // fade the LAST item out
                $list.find('> li:last').animate({ opacity : .5 ,"margin-top":height/3}, 500, function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                });

                $insert.animate({"margin-top":0,opacity : 1 }, 500).animate({opacity : 1},1000);

                currentItem++;

                total=smplet.find('> li').length;
                if (currentItem >= total) {
                    currentItem = 0;
                }         

                if (total == 1){
                    simpleSpy.stop();
                }   
                else if(total == 0){
                    $("#topbar").hide();
                }                   

                timec=setTimeout(spy, interval);
            });

            currentItem++; 

            function spy() {            
                var temp=smplet.find('> li').eq(currentItem).clone();

                var $insert = temp.css({
                    "margin-top":-height-height/3,
                    opacity : 0,
                    display : 'none'
                }).prependTo($list);

                $list.find('> li:last').animate({ opacity : .5 ,"margin-top":height/3}, 500, function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                });
                $insert.animate({"margin-top":0,opacity : 1 }, 500).animate({opacity : 1},1000);
                    $insert.css("display","");

                currentItem++;          

                if (currentItem >= total) {
                    currentItem = 0;
                }

                timec=setTimeout(spy, interval);

             }
                timec=setTimeout(spy, interval);        
        });     

    }; 

    $('ul.alerts')
    .mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timec);
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        timec=setTimeout(spy, interval);
    });  

})(jQuery);
```

Call

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul.alerts').simpleSpy();

 });
```

jsfiddle with html and css

http://jsfiddle.net/1781367/3eK4K/3/

Comment: Can't run your fiddle because of errors: 1. spy is not defined, 2. simple spy is not defined

Comment: could you open from firefox or chrome?

Comment: I am working in chrome, it still says spy is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the timeout, which you were setting over and over, to an interval, which you only need to set once. Then I added a "paused" property that is set to true on mouseover and back to false on mouseout.

```
var paused = false;
$list.mouseover(function() { paused = true; });
$list.mouseout(function() { paused = false; });
```

Then we just check that property before the rotation animation occurs:

```
if (paused) { 
    return; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3eK4K/6/